# Не вешается событие keydown javascript

Tags: javascript

Привет все есть такой код

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  document.addEventListener("keyDown", checkKeyDown, false);
  document.addEventListener("keyUp", checkKeyUp, false);

}

function checkKeyDown(e) {
  alert("Кнопка нажата");
  var keyId = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(keyId);

  if (keyChar == "W") {
    player.isUp = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (keyChar == "S") {
    player.isDown = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (keyChar == "D") {
    player.isRight = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (keyChar == "A") {
    player.isLeft = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

при нажатии должен кричать alert('') но почему то ничего не сработало, почему?

Comment: Попробуйте `keydown` и `keyup` в нижнем регистре написать.

Comment: мда уж( спасибо! помогли,

Answer (score 0):

`keyDown` и `keyUp` - должны быть в нижнем регистре: `keydown`, `keyup`. Вернхий регистр можно встретить только у `DOMContentLoaded`

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyDown, false);
}

function checkKeyDown(e) {
  alert("Кнопка нажата");
  var keyId = e.keyCode || e.which;
  var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(keyId);

  if (keyChar == "W") {
    player.isUp = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (keyChar == "S") {
    player.isDown = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (keyChar == "D") {
    player.isRight = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (keyChar == "A") {
    player.isLeft = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```